# Access model fields from website with javascript - Odoo v9 community

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, odoo-9

I'm wondering, if I add a button to send an email from a `website` page in my Odoo module.

If it's "pure" javascript, something like this:

```
<textarea id="myText">
Lorem ipsum...
</textarea>
<button onclick="sendMail(); return false">Send</button>
function sendMail() {
var link = "mailto:me@example.com"
         + "?cc=myCCaddress@example.com"
         + "&subject=" + escape("This is my subject")
         + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('myText').value)
;

window.location.href = link;
}
```

Suppose the email, should be a field I set up on `res_company` for that, let's say `loan_email`, just for example.

Is there a way I could access that field from javascript on a Odoo website page?

I mean, instead of just sending the email as this example does, to actually send it, from the email field set up on `res_company` ?

I hope I've explained myself, if You have doubts please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can access any of the filed of any of the model using javascript. You just need to insert some code for that. I already done this thing in POS. So I know how to do this.

You have to insert this lines in starting of the js files:

```
odoo.define('your model name'  function (require) {"use strict";//your code});
```

After this for accessing field you have to create template for that in xml and call that template in your js file. Make sure that template contain field which is there in your .py file after that for calling that template is like this:

```
var varnm = jsfile_which_used_in_frontend.extend({

template: 'templatename',
action: function(){
method_or_action({'field_name'});
},
 });//end of code
```

Also if you want to use functionality of another js file which here i used (**jsfile_which_used_in_frontend**) in your js file then you can do like this:

> create a variable like this:

```
var varname=require('model name')
```

If your file is in another model and if you want to access that then you have to do like this instead of previous variable creation line:

```
var varnm=require('foldername.filename')
```

If you have any question regarding this feel free to ask and if you feel this answer helpful then up vote or make it valid answer.

**Thank you**